# Is there an English translation of Newton’s De Analysi?

Tags: mathematics, reference-request, calculus, newton, translations

I’m looking for an English translation of Newton’s *De analysi*. (Alas, my Latin is weak.) I’m rather dismayed by the fact that I can’t appear to find one. How is it possible that one of the most important texts in the history of science has gone untranslated into English for the public domain? (The Latin is [here](http://www.newtonproject.ox.ac.uk/view/texts/normalized/NATP00204).)

I’m aware D. T. Whiteside has volumes that collect Newton’s work: there is *Mathematical Works* published by Johnson Reprint Corp. in 1964, and then also a multivolume series with Cambridge University Press, *Mathematical Papers*. But these volumes cost hundreds of dollars and are hard to access. And again dismayingly, there is no preview available on Google Books: I cannot tell whether the *De Analysi* that appears in these volumes is in Latin or English.

Comment: See [Sir Isaac Newton's two treatises (1745)](https://books.google.it/books?id=noQ_AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA344)

Comment: @Mauro Allegranza: thank you! You should put that in an answer so I can upvote it. Still, I am rather shocked there isn’t some newer edition... or some English full text in a more readily readable version online...

Answer (score 3):

See [Sir Isaac Newton's two treatises of the quadrature of curves and analysis by equations of an infinite number of terms (1745)](https://books.google.it/books?id=noQ_AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA344).